# Prove or disprove that $D_n (U(n)) \simeq _H \{z \in \mathbb{C} :|Re(z)|= \sqrt{1/2}-|Im(z)|\}$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, geometric-topology

We have that $U(n) = \{X \in GL_n(\mathbb{C}): X^*X= XX^* = I_n\}$, where $ X^* = \overline{X}^T $ and $D_n: GL_n \to \mathbb{C} /\{0\}, X\to \det (X)$, I proved that $D_n(U_n)=S^1$ where $S^1=\{z \in C : |z|=1\}$, the I have a question, if $S^1 \simeq_H \{z \in \mathbb{C} :|Re(z)|= \sqrt{1/2}-|Im(z)|\}$

Comment: Did you really mean $X^X=XX^=I_n?$ Presumably you wanted an $X^*$ somewhere, since you defined it.

Comment: And what does $\simeq_H$ mean?

Comment: $X^*$ typographic error

Comment: $\simeq_H$ is homeomorphic

Comment: The right side of $\simeq_H$ can be scaled to $\{(x,y)\mid |x|+|y|=1\},$ which is a square, which is homeomorphic to a circle.

Comment: Still not sure what $X^*=XX^=I_n$ means. Do you mean $X^*X=XX^*=I_n?$

Comment: That's right, and then build a homeomorphism between $\{|x|+|y|=1\}$ and $\{|x|+|y|=\sqrt{1/2}\}$

Answer (score 0):

If you know that $D_n(U(n)) = S^1$, it remains to show that $S^1 \approx S = \{z \in \mathbb{C} :|Re(z)|= \sqrt{1/2}-|Im(z)|\}$. Identifying $\mathbb R^2$ with $\mathbb C$ via $(x,y) \mapsto x + iy$ we see that $S = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 :|x| + |y| = \sqrt{1/2}\}$. But the expression $\lVert (x,y) \rVert_1 = |x| + |y|$ provides a norm on $\mathbb R^2$. Thus $S = \{\xi \in \mathbb{R}^2 :\lVert \xi \rVert_1 = \sqrt{1/2}\}$.

Define continuous maps
$$h : S^1  \to S, h(\xi)  = \sqrt{1/2}\frac{\xi}{\lVert \xi \rVert_1},$$
$$g : S \to S^1, g(\eta)  = \frac{\eta}{\lVert \eta \rVert_2},$$
where $\lVert -\rVert_2$ is the Euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^2$. It is an easy exercise to show that $g \circ h = id$ and $h \circ g = id$.  Thus $h$ and $g$ are homeomorphisms which are inverse to each other.